# How to implement references between objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, reference

I am looking for the correct way to store references to objects in javascript.

For example I have an object customer:

```
function Customer(n) {
  this.name = n;
}
```

And an array of all customers, that gets filled:

```
var customers = new Array()
customers.push(new Customer('Alfred'));
customers.push(new Customer('Bob'));
```

Now I also have several other objects which reference customers, like `purchase`, and `outstandingOffer`, `promotion` ect. which should all reference to elements of the customers array. For example:

```
function Purchase(i, c) {
  this.customer = c; // ? <- this need to be a reference
  this.item = i; 
}
```

This could be done by storing the index in the array, but that seems fragile in case a customer needs to be removed. What is the best way to store a reference to another object in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `new` to create object

```
var customers = new Array()
customers.push(new Customer('Alfred'));
customers.push(new Customer('Bob'));

function Purchase(i, c) {
  this.customer = c; // ? <- this need to be a reference
  this.item = i; 
}

var Purchase_obj = new Purchase(2,customers[0] );
```

Comment: if I change the name of the customer, will that show up in the purchase? what happens when a customer in customers gets deleted?

Comment: @Beginner if you update customer name that will reflect in purchase object, that is the main concept of `oop` , if you remove one customer from customers array it will not be destroyed, you can still get customer name from purchase object

Answer (score 1):

looking at below you approach is different

```
var customers = new Array()
customers.push(new Customer('Alfred'));
customers.push(new Customer('Bob'));
```

You are pushing new objects in an array without saving a reference to it.So your purchase function will never know **what is who or who is what**

This is How I would approach it

```
function Customer(n) {
  this.name = n;
  this.items=[];
  this.addPurchase=function(item){
  this.items.push(item);
  }
}
```

**The above function will have the follow**

1. The name of the customer
2. A function that adds an item to the customer item cart
3. An item cart

```
var customers = {}; //create a big object that stores all customers
customers.Alfred=new Customer('Alfred'); // create a new object named Alfred
customers.Bob=new Customer('Bob'); // create a new object named Bob
customers.John=new Customer('John'); // create a new object named John
```

Using console.log, you will get

```
Alfred: Object, Bob: Object, John: Object
```

**If you want to add items to Alfred you do this**

```
customers.Alfred.addPurchase('pineapple');
```

**If you want to add items to Bob you do this**

```
customers.Bob.addPurchase('mango');
```

**If you want to add items to John you do this**

```
customers.John.addPurchase('coconut');
```

This is output from `console.log(customers.John.items);`

```
Array [ "coconut" ]
```

**So what if we want to delete a customer?**
We already have a reference to it!

```
delete customers.John;
```

John and this history is gone!...Verify it is deleted

```
console.log(customers);
```

output

```
Object { Alfred: Object, Bob: Object }
```